# Efficiently default ranges

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, math, set, switch-statement

I'd like to set defaults for a set of ranges.

here are my defaults:

```
options = {0: 'red',  20: 'yellow', 50: 'blue', 80: 'green'}
```

here is my argument

```
value = 10
```

how do I efficiently create this:

```
case value
when value < 10
  'red'
when value < 20
  'yellow'
when value < 50
  'blue'
when value < 80
  'gold'
else
  'green'
```

from an object/hash data type?

Comment: Your options hash doesn't match your case statement; you don't have an option for gold.  Just to make sure we get what you have in mind.

Answer (score 3):

In ruby case statements can take ranges. It's pretty sweet actually...

```
color = case value
        when (0...10)
          'red'
        when (10...20)
          'yellow'
        when (20...30)
          'blue'
        when (30...40)
          'gold'
        else
         'green'
```